# Xcode how to use IBOutlet to label while used in function

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, function

I have connection to my label:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *scoreBox;
```

correctly, and I'm trying to access it like this:

```
void namedfunction(button) {

    if (button == button) {
        score = score + 100;
        [scoreBox setIntValue:score];
      // ^ error
    }
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

> AppDelegate.m:52:10: Use of undeclared identifier 'scoreBox'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
[_scoreBox setIntValue:score];
```

Or

```
[self.scoreBox setIntValue:score];
```

**Also check that you are ending up with comparing same button, as : `button==button`.*

EDIT 2:

As your code is :

```
int perus(int nappi){

}
```

Change it to:

```
- (NSInteger *)perus:(NSInteger *)nappi{
    //all should do inside, rest are OK.
}
```

<strike>EDIT:</strike>

I am not sure about the following as found this [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/158356-iboutlets-out-of-scope-in-functions.html)

**I would suggest you to switch to obj-c method instead of using a C function for this sort of thing.*

A C function is just that, a block of code not attached to anything
else. Your instance variable is attached to each Controller object.
So when you call printChatter() there is no way to know which
instance of Controller you want to use. You could add an object
variable to your function:

```
void namedfunction(const void *button, const void *appDele){
    NSTextField *myButton=[appDele scoreBox];
    ....
}
```

Comment: @user2225385: show your full code of AppDelegate.m and AppDelegate.h

Comment: you have a C function, why dont you switch to an obj-C method?